# TerminateProcess ExitCode

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to better my understanding of some of the process APIs, namely GetExitCodeProcess and TerminateProcess.  I've found a number of code examples on the internet, but not quite the explanation I'm looking for.

I understand that this will give me the exit code of a process.

```
lResult = GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, lExitCode)
```

And this will terminate the process

```
lResult = TerminateProcess(hProcess, lExitCode)
```

However, it seems that this last exit code parameter does not have to be the exit code retrieved in the first line.  In fact, I've come across quite a few examples where `0` has been substituted for the exit code.

```
lResult = TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0)
```

I thought lExitCode was a specific value I had to provide to the TerminateProcess function, but apparently that's not the case - it seems that almost any number will work.  Could someone give me an explanation on this?

Comment: How is your question connected with Excel VBA?

Comment: @xmojmr - To be truthful, I wasn't sure what tag I should use, but as I was using these api functions in an Excel VBA environment, I was looking for a reply in "VBA speak", as opposed to `C`, for example.

Comment: Do you use Visual Basic (`vb6` tag) or you want to call `TerminateProcess` from an Excel macro to shut Excel down or you want to call `TerminateProcess` from an Excel macro to kill different process and fake it's exit code?

Comment: I'm using `TerminateProcess` (and related API's) in an Excel application.  Part of this application's function involves shelling to various external applications as required (calc.exe, notepad, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can pass any number you want as the second parameter to `TerminateProcess()`.  There is no correct value to pass.  Windows does not care what this value is.  It's only purpose is for other applications to check what value was passed in using `GetExitCodeProcess()`.

What the values passed to `TerminateProcess()` are, are application defined.  So they can mean whatever you want them to mean.  For example you could define 0 as meaning that the application completed successfully, 1 if there was no Internet connection, 2 if the server was down, etc.  If no one is listening for the exit code of your application it is irrelevant want you send, since no one will ever check it.

Also in your examples, for

```
lResult = GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, lExitCode)
```

`lExitCode` is an output parameter, it will be filled in with the processes exit code on return.  However in

```
lResult = TerminateProcess(hProcess, lExitCode)
```

`lExitCode` in an input parameter, so whatever value is stored in `lExitCode` will be passed in.  So for example these two statements are identical:

```
lExitCode = 0
lResult = TerminateProcess(hProcess, lExitCode)
```

and

```
lResult = TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0)
```

Comment: Just return the windows error code if exiting because of an error. Else return 0. In the command prompt these are used to indicate command status. Some programs have specific return codes, eg; `find` and `findstr` return 0 if found, 1 if not found, and 2 if error.

Comment: Thank you, your answer has shed new light for me on this topic.  I find the MSDN explanations are sometimes a bit cryptic, at least for a newbie.

Comment: A followup comment - part of my confusion comes, in part, from reading other publications on this subject.  `Applications Interface Programming Using Multiple Languages`, for instance, specifically indicates that you need to call `GetExitCodeProcess()` to retrieve the exit code, then call `TerminateProcess() using that retrieved exit code.  But from your answer (and my own experimentation), this appears to be incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

From perspective of shelling various external applications from within Excel macro there are basically two scenarios:

### 1) spawned process terminates normally

[image]

### 2) spawned process is terminated abnormally (killed)

[image]

The later case should be used carefully because

> ...The TerminateProcess function is used to unconditionally cause a process to exit. The **state of** global **data** maintained by dynamic-link libraries (DLLs) **may be compromised** if TerminateProcess is used rather than ExitProcess...
>
> ...A process cannot prevent itself from being terminated
>
> <sub>Source: [MSDN: Windows → Dev Center-Desktop → TerminateProcess function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>

Also note that the exit code parameter is treated as input in

```
Declare Function TerminateProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal uExitCode As Long) As Long
```

and as output (ByRef) in

```
Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByRef lpExitCode As Long) As Long
```

Both functions follow same success/error calling convention

> Return value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
>   If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError
>
> (Visual Basic:  Applications should call err.LastDllError instead of GetLastError)
>
> <sub>Source: MSDN: [TerminateProcess function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx), [GetExitCodeProcess function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx), [GetLastError function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>

Comment: An excellent illustration!  Unfortunately I can't accept 2 answers, but I've incremented the `this answer is useful` counter.  Thanks.

Comment: @DaveU I've incremented the `this question is useful` counter. Thanks